# How do I unit test streaming download using jersey / dropwizard?

Tags: unit-testing, jersey, dropwizard

I have a resource method which produces a streaming download:

```
@GET
@Path("/{assetId}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response download(@PathParam("assetId") String assetId) {
    StreamingOutput stream = os -> service.download(assetId, os);
    return Response.ok(stream).build();
}
```

I want to unit test this with a mock service object. I already have:

```
private static AssetsService service = Mockito.mock(AssetsService.class);

@ClassRule
public final static ResourceTestRule resource = ResourceTestRule.builder()
    .addResource(new AssetsResource(service))
    .addProvider(MultiPartFeature.class)
    .build();


@Test
public void testDownload() {
    reset(service);
    // how to get an output stream from this?
    resource.client().target("/assets/123").request().get();
}
```

Per my comment in the test, what do I need to do in order to get an outputstream from the response? I find the jersey client API pretty confusing.

Once I have this, I'll stub the service call so that it writes a known file, and test that it's received correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Response response = resource.client().target("/assets/123").request().get();

InputStream is = response.readEntity(InputStream.class);
```